# Is it possible to download cloudfront certificate onto EC2 server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, amazon-cloudfront

I have an EC2 Instance with a cloudfront certificate issued to its origin. It is in use but I get an error when trying to access it.

```
CloudFront wasn't able to connect to the origin.
```

After some research I have realized that my setup was done correctly through ACM but The server is not sending the required intermediate certificate. (I tested it using https://www.digicert.com/help/) After consulting with some friends and reading some other answers on SO I found out that I need to install a intermediate certificate onto my server but cant seem to figure it out using ACM.

Comment: The Intermediate certificate isn't from CloudFront or ACM.  The intermediate certificate comes from the issuer of the certificate you installed on your EC2 instance.  Who did you purchase that certificate from?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I didnt purchase I ticket. I was trying to issue one through ACM maybe I misunderstood how it works?

Comment: If I have a certificate issued for a different site is it possible to use it for my api? for instance I have a ticket purchased for www.mysite.com can I use it for api.mysite.com?